# How do we name hexadecimal numbers?

Tags: terminology, number-systems

In the standard base 10 numbers that humans are so used to, we for example call the number 26 in English, "twenty six."

This number is represented as 1A in base 16 hexadecimal. Is 1A still called "twenty six?" Note that we *could* call 26 "two six" but we don't usually do that. Likewise, we don't usually call 1000 "one oh oh oh" but rather "one thousand." Is this convention also followed for base 16 numbers? Are there separate names for base-16 even numbers similar to "fifty, sixty, seventy, one hundred thousand" and so on?

Comment: What do you know about binary? Any non-base $10$ number system functions similarly (e.g. $10100_2$ is "base two one-zero-one-zero-zero", as $10100_{16}$ is "base sixteen one-zero-one-zero-zero").

Comment: Wikipedia's "Hexadecimal" entry includes a section ["Verbal and digital representations"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal#Verbal_and_digital_representations), listing three naming systems. The Magnussen system pronounces "1AD0" as "annteen dotty", the Rogers method pronounces "1743" as "one-thousek-seven-hundrek-fourtek-three", and Babb pronounced "1D" as "dibbleteen". ... Personally, I just read the digits.

Comment: @Blue wow, today I learn! I've always thought decimal was just, _special_.

Comment: @AndrewChin: It's new to me, too. I simply did a web search for "hexadecimal naming convention".

Comment: Well, $1A_{16}$ and $26_{10}$ are both the same number.  What you *call* them is up to you.  Because we are earthlings with a relatively global education when we talk about numbers it is assume we mean base $10$ so when we say "twentysix" it is assumed we mean the number that is twice the sixth prime.  But if we are talking *about* hexidecimal numbers it wouldn't really make sense to refer to the *decimal* digits.  So *somehow* we are likely to refer to this as "one-A".  "Ateen" makes sense but seems silly to me.  Math is *better* than english in talking  of numbers so imitate english?

Comment: @fleablood "A-teen" runs into an issue when you compare to the number that is two less. Depending on how you pronounce it.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers are numbers regardless of what we call them or how we choose to represent them.  XXVI, $26$, $1A_{16}$, $2\sqrt{169}$, "twenty-six", "one ai in hex", "11010", $28_9$, $35_7$ etc. are all the same *number*.

We are, however, earthlings who have taken on a base ten decimal system so when we say $26$ or "twenty-six", it is understood we mean $2\times 10 + 6$.  Its only when specifically talking of other bases for the *sake* of talking of other bases that we refer to numbers by their *representation*.  So we say $1A_{16}$ we are specifically drawing attention to its representation.  We wouldn't say "It is 'twenty-six'" unless we are specifically indicating its *value* and as base 10 is abitrary we'd probable, to avoid confusion say "This would be the number 'twenty-six' in our more common base $10$" or words to that effect.

Now that's not to say we wouldn't refer to $26_{16} = 2*16 + 6$ (which, irrelevantly, is $38_{10}$) as "twenty-six in hex".  We probably *would* say that.  If they look like numbers we're used to we'll probably refer to numbers we are used to.  I'd probably refer to $1000_{16}$ as "one thousand in base sixteen" but more likely I'd refer to it by function as somthing like "sixteen to the fourth".  Something like $1,324$ (i.e. $16^4+ 3*16^2 + 2*16 + 4$).  I really doubt I'd say "one thousand three hundred twenty four" because "thousand" and "hundred" seem, to me at least, to imply base $10$.

And as in the comment section there are people addressing the issue https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal#Verbal_and_digital_representations but IMO this is a bit silly.  No-one cares what you *verbally* say and this is unnatural .... at least for now.